# List of String to List of list of integers

Tags: java, stream

Hey so I have list of String like "1,2,3" and I want to get List of list of integers
I know how to map one String to List of integers, but I am struggling with making List of list.

So far I came up with:

```
   List<String> lines = getLines(s);
        List<List<Integer>> nestedList=lines.stream()
                .map((z->Arrays.stream(z.split(","))
                        .map(Integer::parseInt)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you add an example of an input and your expected output?

Comment: Input would be list of  Strings like {("1,2,3","1,1,1","7,6,5")} and ouput would be List of List like so  {{1,2,3},{1,1,1}, {7,6,5}}, I have list of strings and I want to convert each string to list of integers and from that I should get list of list of integers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By mapping each entry of the list to a list of integers then collect all its should work

```
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1,2,3","1,1,1","7,6,5");
        list.stream()
            .map(e-> Arrays.stream(e.split(","))
                .map(Integer::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Although the accepted answer was provided first, the more functional approach of this slightly later answer has some pretty clear advantages over that more imperative one. This is a case where it may be worth considering changing the accepted answer to one provided later, imo.

Comment: The selected answer was answered 3 minutes after this one.. but still.. thanks for your comment mate

Comment: I meant to choose this one. I liked both answers and I thought I can accept both of them. Thank a lot.

Comment: Interesting, @Timor. For some reason it looked to me at first like it was the other way around. But it appears you are correct about that timing. This makes it even more interesting that the other one was chosen, which does not take advantage of the newer Java Stream api.

Comment: @thomas1413 I see. Just FYI, I believe you can always change your accepted answer if you decide another one is better.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use streams but does the job:

```
List<String> lines = getLines(s);
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> nested_list=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
for(String s:lines){
  String[] tokens=s.split(",");
  ArrayList<Integer> tmp=new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for(int i=0;i<tokens.length;++i){
    int n=Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
    tmp.add(n);
  }
  nested_list.add(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With actual Java, a functional approach would be:

```
List<String> lines = getLines(s);
var splitter = Pattern.compile(",");
List<List<Integer>> nestedList = lines.stream()
                                      .map(splitter::splitAsStream)
                                      .map(s -> s.map(Integer::valueOf))
                                      .map(Stream::toList)
                                      .toList();
```

(Java 16 is required for `toList()`, otherwise `collect(Collectors.toList())` can be used instead)